# Dropdown menu relative positionning leaves gap between main menu items

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-position

I've been searching all over stackoverflow but found nothing similar.

I have a vertical (normal) menu with 1 submenu I want to be to the right of the main menu without leaving a gap to the menu items that come after it.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pzyLR/

HTML

```
<ul class="sidemenu">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>        
<li><a href="">History</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">1st page</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">2nd page</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">3rd page</a></li> 
        <li><a href="">4th page</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">A-Z index</a></li> 
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li> 
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.sidemenu {
list-style-type:none;
padding:10px 0px;
margin:0;
text-align:center;
}

ul.sidemenu li {
margin:5px 0px;
}

ul.sidemenu li a {
display:block;
line-height:20px;
padding:10px 0px;
width:200px;
background-color: rgba(28,28,28, 0.16);
font-family:arial;
font-size:1.4em;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#1c1c1c;
text-decoration:none;
}

/*dropdown menu*/

ul.sidemenu li ul {
display:none;
list-style-type:none;
}

ul.sidemenu li:hover > ul {
display:block;
width:120px;
position:relative; left:20%; top:-45px;
}
```

As you can see in the demo the drop down menu does position correctly tough it still leaves a huge white space as it if is there too.

Any suggestions? I already tried absolute positioning but when I resize the browser window it will go out of its desired place.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` to first **UL** and second **UL**. Then position the Elements with left, top, bottom values

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pzyLR/2/)

**UPDATED CSS**

```
ul.sidemenu {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px 0px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}

ul.sidemenu li {
    margin:5px 0px;
}

ul.sidemenu li a {
    display:block;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:10px 0px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: rgba(28,28,28, 0.16);
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:1.4em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#1c1c1c;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/*dropdown menu*/

ul.sidemenu li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul.sidemenu li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    position:absolute;
    left:82%; 
    top:27%;
}
```

**1.** Added `position:absolute;` to **ul.sidemenu**.

**2.** Changed `position:relative;` to `position:absolute;` in `ul.sidemenu li:hover > ul` and also changed values of `left` and `top` in same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two divs: in first you can put your main menu, in second your submenu. So try insert submenu `<ul>` element in one `div`, and insert your `<ul>` in another `div`. Now if you hover on main menu `li` element, in `div` on the right you can show your submenu.

Simple example:

```
<div>
   <ul class='mainmenu'>....</ul>
</div>
<div>
   <ul class='submenu'>....</ul>
</div>
```